# Remove values from python list without changing indexs

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

I want to remove a values from python list without changing the index.
For example, if list is [20,30,40] , if I want remove the 20 from the list.
that list index become 30-0 and 40-1.but I need 30-1 and 40-2.
Is there any solution to my problem??

Comment: You can set the value you want to remove to a sentinel value like `None` instead of removing. But you have to make sure you handle the sentinel value in any further logic

Comment: You are looking for a dictionary with keys as indices. Python lists don't give the capability that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dictionaries:

```
assoc = { 0:20, 1:30, 2:40}
print( assoc[2] )
del assoc[1]
print( assoc[2] )
print(assoc)
```

Running this gives:

```
40
40
{0: 20, 2: 40}
```